# How can I run the sudo command in Python code under CentOS in Docker

Tags: command-line, bash, python, docker, container

I am trying to access the docker image labels from Python as follows

```
hostname = socket.gethostname()
cmd = "sudo curl --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http:/containers/" + hostname + "/json"
output = os.popen(cmd).read()
```

But, the thing is I am getting the following error:

```
We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

It's one of the fancy messages by Unix from some other posts I read from StackOverflow.

I am following the below link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37439887/how-to-access-the-metadata-of-a-docker-container-from-a-script-running-inside-th

Only thing is I want to run these things from Python not from the Terminal.
Also, FYI, I get the response when I run the same command from the terminal.

I tried appending the following piece in Dockerfile

```
RUN echo "root ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
```

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to do this? I mean, why would you run `curl` as sudo? There's no point in doing that unless you need to write the output to a directory only root has access to. If that is the case, why aren't you running the script as `sudo`?

Comment: I think you are mixing the concepts of host and Docker container.

Comment: Or change the permissions on the directory. Also note you sudo snip-it gives root permission to run sudo (Why: root already can do anything).

Comment: What OS are you doing this on?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` configuration by default has `requiretty` set so that password authentication is known as reliably as possible to be presented to an actual meatbag rather than to standard input.  This is checked even if `NOPASSWD` is set for a specific `sudoers` entry.

First, I would suggest you look long and hard at why you need to `sudo curl` in the first place.  This is highly ill-advised as a general rule -- you don't need to be 'root' to run `curl` to pull something from a remote host.  Run `curl` as a non-priveleged user and if you need superuser access to do something with whatever you've fetched, do that separately.

*All that said*, you can either disable `requretty` for the specific `sudoers` entry or for the entire configuration, and a TTY will no longer be required.

Comment: I think from the comments and discussion I got my answer. I was confused between `Operation not permitted` and `Permission denied`. For resolving and getting rid of both of these I was thinking that `sudo` is the solution. But, for permission denied we have to change the permissions preferably using `chown` and later execute whatever we want. @ctrl-alt-delor, I am doing this on CentOS and the host OS is Mac OS. And yes, we should not use `sudo` to run curl on our system, because there is no need.